# React native - Allow scroll inside absolute positionated TouchableOpacity

Tags: react-native, scroll, absolute, touchableopacity

I have a view with a list of items. The user can click on the menu button of each item and trigger the copy function which will show a button on each item, so that the user can "paste" the selected item and copy it to many other items.

In this image, the user is copying Item 1 into Item 4, 5 and 6.

[image]

When the user activate the copy mode, an absolute positioned `TouchableOpacity` is set in order to capture clicks outside the checkboxes and inform the user if he wants to exit the copy mode. I do that to force the user exit the copy mode.

This however poses the problem that the user is not able to scroll anymore.

Is there a way to detect that the user is scrolling and not clicking the `TouchableOpacity`?
(Apparently on android I'm able to scroll, while on ios it detects the scroll as a `onPress` event

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try onLongPress instead of onPress?

Comment: Hi, onLongPress does not work :( same behavior